# BsonExtraElements Dictionary<string, Object> and custom classes as value fails serialization

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, bson

Having the following class:

```
public class Article
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements()]
    public Dictionary<string, Object> OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add this object to the dictionary and write to the database:

```
public class Bird
{
    [BsonElement("_n")]
    [BsonRequired]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("_s")]
    [BsonRequired]
    public string Species { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("_a")]
    [BsonRequired]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var col = db.GetCollection<Article>("articles");

var art = new Article
{
    Name = "Blu"
};

art.OtherData = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "bird" , new Bird { Name = "Jerry", Age = 4, Species = "European starling" } }
};

col.InsertOne(art);
```

However this fails with the following exception: System.ArgumentException: '.NET type Bird cannot be mapped to a BsonValue'

If I remove the `[BsonExtraElements]` attribute, all goes fine and the article ends up in the database. Why is this? How does the attribute prevent serialization? Because with the attribute not being there, this custom class of mine can be serialized by the driver.

Using driver version 2.4.4

Comment: I have reported this at mongodb's [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2035). They've looked into it and responded: `It's not really intended behavior. We currently assume that all the values in the BsonExtraElements dictionary are either instances of BsonValue or trivially convertible to BsonValue. We should be able to convert more complex values like your Bird class by using a serializer.

We will consider supporting this in a future release.`

Answer (score 1):

Official doc (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/):

> You can design your class to be capable of handling any extra elements that might be found in a BSON document during deserialization. To do so, you must have a property of type **BsonDocument** and you must identify that property as the one that should hold any extra elements that are found (or you can name the property “ExtraElements” so that the default ExtraElementsMemberConvention will find it automatically).

```
public MyClass {
// fields and properties
[BsonExtraElements]
public BsonDocument CatchAll { get; set; }
}
```

Long story short it needs to be BsonDocument type when you use [BsonExtraElements] tag.

Cheers!

EDIT: I got it working by adding

```
{ "bird" , new Bird { Name = "Jerry", Age = 4, Species = "European starling" }.ToBsonDocument() }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However the documentation you link is old. I'm using the 2.4 version of the C# driver. There it is possible to add the `[BsonExtraElements]` to a [dictionary](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#supporting-extra-elements). `To do so, you must have a property of type BsonDocument (or IDictionary<string, object>)`

Comment: Ohh you didn't specify driver version so i tough it was that. Did you try renaming member to ExtraElements?

Comment: I gave that a go, but I'm still getting the same error with the field renamed. I also edited the question to include the driver version.

Comment: look at edit. I edited answer for readability. Hope it is solved now =)

Comment: Thanks for helping find a solution. This adds it correctly to the database, but upon retrieval it is filled in a `Dictionary<string, Object>`, containing the _n, _s, _a keys rather then a `Bird` object. This is unfortunate, as I would like whatever class I add to the database to be deserialized back into that specific class. But we're making progress :)

Comment: BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Bird>(doc.OtherData["bird"]);

Comment: This is not realy the solution I'm looking for, as this would require me to know the type of every field when I'm deserializing it. Thanks for your effort though, have an upvote. I've reported this at mongo's [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2035). They'll potentially include this functionality in a future release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153899/discussion-between-bor4-and-bjorn-de-rijcke).

Answer (score -1):

Use **`[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]`** instead

```
public class Article
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
    public Dictionary<string, Object> OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

this will generate JSON like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a468f3e28fad22e08c4fa6b"),
    "Name": "Sanjay",
    "OtherData": {
        "stringData": "val1",
        "boolVal": true,
        "someObject": {
            "key1": "val1",
            "key2": "val2"
        },
        ...
    }

}
```